# Ruby on Rails API - Creation of Database Objects only returns objects with empty values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, api, authentication, rubygems

I have a Ruby on Rails JSON API with Knock for JWT Authentification.

The **User model** looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

attr_accessor :email, :password, :password_digest
has_secure_password

end
```

And the **Migration**:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.string :email
            t.string :password
            t.string :password_digest

            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

There is also a User-Controller with scaffolded CRUD-Methods. To Generate JWT, I use the following Controller, which is inherited from the Knock::AuthTokenController:

```
class UserTokenController < Knock::AuthTokenController
end
```

However, when I generate a User with the console like this...

```
User.create(:email => 'test.test@test.com', :password => 'test', :password_digest => 'test')
```

... I get a database object with empty values:
[image: Console Output]

Comment: try `User.create!(email: ... )` to raise the error

Comment: No, that doesn't raise an error. It's the same as in the picture, the object is created with empty values :(

Comment: If you are using `ActiveRecord` remove `attr_accessor`. You don't need it and it may cause this kind of problems

Comment: Great it worked! Thank you.

Comment: The weird thing is, when I call a get-request for the index method of the users controller, I get a 404 response, saying: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=):
`... Any ideas on that? :)

Comment: Can you please upvote my question and accept it

Comment: Yeah sure, but do you have any suggestions on the other problem?

Comment: I need to see your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `attr_accessor` since you are using `ActiveRecord`.

Remove this line

```
attr_accessor :email, :password, :password_digest
```